# Windows 8 boots into blue screen and hangs, no error message

Tags: windows-8.1

Sometimes my computer will boot into a blue screen with no error message, so it doesn't look like a bsod. On key press the screen flickers but then when I restart my computer, my computer loads normally.

Cheers,

Alex

Comment: And open an elevated Command Prompt and use `sfc /scannow`

Answer (score 0):

Check for any disk error using chkdsk command. Also verify whether this issue occurs after any windows drivers installation. If it driver issue reinstalling it will fix the issue